# Count the tr table and add the class when the account is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The whole question is in the title.

I have :

```
<table>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
</table>
```

And i would like :

```
<table>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr> <td><img></td> </tr>

(rows > 5 : add class)

<tr class=""> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr class=""> <td><img></td> </tr>
<tr class=""> <td><img></td> </tr>
</table>
```

How i can do this width jquery ? thx

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: You question is unclear. Please provide more details or it should be closed.

Comment: `if ($("tr").length > 5)  { $("tr").addClass("myClass"); }`

Comment: `[...theTable.rows].slice(5).forEach(r => r.classList.add("theClass"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since arrays start at 0 you can use the [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector like this:

```
$('tr:gt(4)').addClass('foo');
```

By using 4 you will start adding the class on `<tr>` 5 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**:nth-child Selector**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) like this:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(n + 6)').addClass('myClass');
```

where `n` is a number in the set `{0, 1, 2, 3, ...}`.

**Example:**

```js
$("tr:nth-child(n + 6)").addClass("myClass");
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  background: blue;
}

.myClass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
  <tr><td><img></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: its good too thx !

Answer (score 0):

It exactly what i want thx !

```
$('tr:gt(4)').addClass('foo');
```

or

```
 $('table tr:nth-child(n+6)').addClass('myClass');
```

Solved !